# OpenTSDB vs KairosDB for HBase?

Tags: hbase, opentsdb, kairosdb

My Hadoop stack has HBase. Now I have to decide between OpenTSDB vs KairosDB as a Time Series DB over HBase.

I know the fact that KairosDB is build over Cassandra and also works with HBase. Also have gone through below links that highlight differences between OpenTSDB and KairosDB.

- https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/wiki/Changes

But looking for suggestions (based on experience) as to how KairosDB works with HBase. Or is it recommended to go with OpenTSDB with HBase?

Thanks!

Comment: KairosDB does not support HBase anymore, so if you have HBase, then OpenTSDB is the only option.